# Set package name at top of java files with a string reference (android)?

Tags: android

The package name on top of the java files, can it be set in one spot such as the strings file?

pseudo code

```
 package com.website.app_name;   <=======

 imports....

 public class Main extends Activity{}
```

Comment: haha lame why would there be a down vote and why would you not comment as to why you down voted so the asker could learn from it?

Comment: Don't worry there are people over here who down vote if they don't like the question. Even if it deserves a upvote. :P <<+1>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Java doesn't allow that...

Answer (score 1):

No You can not do that, Like you can not change import statement like `import com.xyz.ABC` with a string.

And why one would even need this.

Comment: up vote for confirm.  As for why say I have 15 files I use in multiple apps type thing.  Thanks